# How to Click on check boxes against some data in the list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to click on two check boxes which are in columns against some data in the column. These two things belong to same table.

I've tried to take read the whole table and then trying to read that particular column and based on the necessary data, trying to select the rows and if those two data are not present then have to move to next page till both the data are not on the same page.

```
WebElement mytable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gridBodyTable' and @class='ms-crm-List-Data']/tbody"));
List<WebElement> rows_table = mytable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));   
int rows_count = rows_table.size();
int count = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < rows_count; row++) {
    //List<WebElement> Columns_row = rows_table.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));            
    List<WebElement> Columns_row = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='gridBodyTable']/tbody/tr/td[18]"));
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (WebElement celtext : Columns_row) {
        strings.add(celtext.getText());
        System.out.println(celtext);
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
        if (celtext.getText().equals("Uganda") && celtext.getText().equals("Dadaab")) {
            Columns_row.get(0).click();
            count++;
        }
        if (count == 2) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (count < 2) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='page_R0' and @title='Load Next Page']")).click();
        readTabl();
    }
}
```

It is simply clicking on next page rather than selecting those two rows

Comment: I think celtext.getText().equals("Uganda") && celtext.getText().equals("Dadaab") should have || where you have &&. I'm not sure if that will make everything work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using condition in xpath to get the column row. With that if your column row has a sibling with input tag which should ideally be a checkbox, then you can try the below code

```
WebElement column = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='gridBodyTable']/./td[(contains(text,'Uganda')) or (contains(text,'Dadab'))]"))
 List<WebElement> checkboxes = column.findElements(By.xpath("./input"))
```

Comment: Where exactly you want me to use in my code. Could you please highlight that.

Comment: This will be the all code to get the checkbox in your table. No need to iterate in the loop. Just replace all your above code witht his.

Answer (score 0):

There are to problems with the logic in the clicking section:

The if checks if the cell text is equals to "Uganda" and equals to "Dadaab", it will always be `false`. You need to use or `||`

If a match was found `Columns_row.get(0)` is clicking the checkbox in the first row, not the one with the text

```
for (WebElement celtext : Columns_row) {
    if (celtext.getText().contains("Uganda") || celtext.getText().contains("Dadaab")) {
        celtext.click();
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What I want is that if both the names are present then only select the rows else switch to next page.

Comment: I tried with Or part as well. This also did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't like this `/tbody/tr/td[18]` stanza as it might be a subject to change
2. It's better to put your country name condition to XPath rather than iterate via [WebElements](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html)

Suggested XPath expression:

```
//table/tr/td[count(//table/tr/th[.='Put your desired column name here']/preceding-sibling::th) + 1]/*[text()='Uganda' or text()='Dadaab']
```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

---

Also be aware that working with [HTML tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics) is much easier with [Table](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements/blob/master/htmlelements-java/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/htmlelements/element/Table.java) class of the [HtmlElements](http://htmlelements.qatools.ru) framework.